# Flash, ActionScript 3: how do you give a the EventListener a function With parameters?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, function, addeventlistener, event-listener

I am trying to to attach a function with parameters to the timer but it says "unrelated type function" is there any way to get around this??

code example:

```
var redoTimer:Timer = new Timer(50);

redoTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, saySomething("helloo"));
redoTimer.start();
```

this wont seem to work but is there a way to pass on arguments???

thanks
Matthy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't really do that, the closest equivalent would be using a small inline function to wrap your own function:

```
var redoTimer:Timer = new Timer(50);

redoTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, function(e:Event):void { saySomething("helloo") } );
redoTimer.start();
```

Comment: Closer equivalent with a function that returns a nested anonymous function (see my post).

Answer (score 3):

The [second parameter](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/events/EventDispatcher.html#addEventListener%28%29) to the `addEventListener` function should be a function. Your code actually executes the method `saySomething("helloo")` and tries to use its return value as the second parameter to the `addEventListener` and hence the error.

Also, the event listener function should accept one and only one argument of type `flash.events.Event`. They can have optional arguments with default values if you want to call them explicitly from your code though.

Answer (score 1):

Out of the box: it only takes 2 extra lines of elegant code to solve this ancient puzzle.

```
stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onClick(true, 123, 4.56, "string"));
function onClick(b:Boolean, i:int, n:Number, s:String):Function {
  return function(e:MouseEvent):void {
    trace("Received " + b + ", " + i + ", " + n + " and " + s + ".");
  };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is possible with a roundabout approach. For the event handler, use a **function that returns a nested anonymous function**.

```
private var textFieldA:TextField = new TextField;
private var textFieldB:TextField = new TextField;

public function setParameterizedTextWhenTextFieldsAreClicked ():void {
    addChild(textFieldA);
    textFieldA.text = 'Text field A';
    textFieldA.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, showCustomMessage("One"));

    addChild(textFieldB);
    textFieldB.text = 'Text field B';
    textFieldB.y = 20;
    textFieldB.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, showCustomMessage("Two"));
    // NOTE: We must use strongly referenced listeners because weakly referenced 
    // listeners **will get garbage collected** because we're returning
    // an anonymous function, which gets defined in the global namespace and  
    // thus, the garbage collector does not have anything pointing to it.
}

private function showCustomMessage (message:String):Function {
    // NOTE: You can store the following function to a class variable
    // to keep it in memory, which would let you use weakly referenced 
    // listeners when using this as an event handler. Many people 
    // would find that awkward. I would discourage that.
    return function (e:MouseEvent):void {
        var textField:TextField = e.target as TextField;
        textField.text = message; // "message" argument is available because 
                                  // this function's scope is kept in memory.
    }
}
```

Bear in mind, the use of anonymous functions and reliance on function scope being kept in memory seem to present garbage collection complications.